Android Studio: App crashing when implementing OSM feature
Special features (pubs, bars) should be displayed on an OSM map. However, when I added the following code, without any error messages, the app crashed every time. Both on the emulator and on my mobile phone. The app was working completely fine before adding these lines.
Note: fetchOSMData() was also added to onCreate method
@OptIn(DelicateCoroutinesApi::class)
private fun fetchOSMData() {
    val url = "https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json];area[name=\"Berlin\"]->.searchArea;(node[\"amenity\"=\"bar\"](area.searchArea);node[\"amenity\"=\"pub\"](area.searchArea);node[\"biergarten\"=\"yes\"](area.searchArea););out body;"

    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        try {
            val response = URL(url).readText()
            val jsonData = JSONObject(response)
            val elements = jsonData.getJSONArray("elements")

            for (i in 0 until elements.length()) {
                val element = elements.getJSONObject(i)
                val lat = element.getDouble("lat")
                val lon = element.getDouble("lon")

                runOnUiThread {
                    val marker = org.osmdroid.views.overlay.Marker(mMap)
                    marker.position = GeoPoint(lat, lon)
                    marker.setAnchor(org.osmdroid.views.overlay.Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER, org.osmdroid.views.overlay.Marker.ANCHOR_BOTTOM)
                    marker.title = "lecker Bierchen"
                    mMap.overlays.add(marker)
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}

